# List<T>.Capacity implementation

Tags: c#, generic-collections

I am looking at the source code for `List<T>`. It has the property:

```
public int Capacity {
get {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
    return _items.Length;
}
set {
    if (value < _size) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.value, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    if (value != _items.Length) {
        if (value > 0) {
            T[] newItems = new T[value];
            if (_size > 0) {
                Array.Copy(_items, 0, newItems, 0, _size);
            }
            _items = newItems;
        }
        else {
            _items = _emptyArray;
        }
    }
}
```

}

What is the point to check `if (value > 0)` as if it is not the case this code will never be reached due to the check `if (value < _size)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting about the case when `value` and `_size` are both 0. See the `else` block referring to an `_emptyArray`. This handles the case shown below.

```
var list = new List<string>(16);
Debug.Assert(list.Count == 0);
Debug.Assert(list.Capacity == 16);
list.Capacity = 0;
```

Comment: What then is `_items.Length` if `_size` is 0?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `_items` can be larger than the number of items in the list. `_size` is the actual number of items in the list. `_items.Lengh - _size` is the number of garbage values sitting in the current `_items` buffer.

Comment: Ah, so `_size` is Count.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Exactly. `_items[0], _items[1], ..., _items[_size - 1]` are the conceptually present items in the list, while `_items[_size], ..., _items[_items.Length - 1]` are unused space that will be filled in as `Add` is called.  This is the standard strategy wherein you allocate a larger array than you actually need right now to avoid too many reallocations.

Comment: `> 0`  faster than `!= 0`?

Comment: @Ksv3n I'd guess it's negligible - both `n != 0` and `n > 0` for a 32-bit int `n` are most likely single CPU instructions.